# NewType incompatible with bounded types

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I’m trying to create some new types in Python. For example:

```py
Time = NewType("Time", float)
Frequency = NewType("Frequency", float)
```

And it’s checked by mypy.

However say have a function `f: Callable[[Time], None]` and use it like `f(0.1)`, it gives an incompatible error until I wrap the `0.1` into `Time(0.1)`, which is quite verbose.

What I want is when I try to pass down a `Frequency` into `f` the type checker gives an error but not normal `float`s. Also `Time` * `float` should gives `Time`, etc.

Are there any ways to accomplish this?

Comment: ... then you **don't want a new type**. The whole *point* of a new type is that it *won't accept just any float*

Comment: So, consider, I have a class `class Foo: ... ` then I make `class Bar(Foo): ...`, then you would expet that `def func(bar: Bar) -> None: ... ` *won't accept* `func(Foo())`.

Comment: In any case, you are going to have to just define these types to have those semantics, but it won't be able to accepts just `0.1`. Because that is always going to be considered a `float`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you should post this as an answer! I've responded with basically this advice on code reviews a number of times. Sometimes a valid answer to *"how do I do this?"* is *"you don't"* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the comments, if you define `Time` and `Frequency` as new types (either via `NewType` or a class), they are not interchangeable with `float` or each other.
That can be a bit frustrating because you might know that, in practice, a `Time` is represented as a `float`. However, the type system does not make this inference because it could lead to errors if you accidentally pass a `float` when a `Time` was expected.

If you really want to avoid having to explicitly convert `float` to `Time` or `Frequency`, you could consider using [type aliases](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#type-aliases) instead of new types:

```py
Time = float
Frequency = float
```

But... that loses the benefit of type checking. With these aliases, a function expecting a `Time` will happily accept a `Frequency` or a plain `float`, because from the perspective of the type checker, they are all the same type.

---

The alternative would be, in your new class, to define the [dunder methods](https://mathspp.com/blog/pydonts/dunder-methods) (`__add__`, `__mul__`, etc.) to implement the desired behavior.

```py
class Time:
    def __init__(self, value: float):
        if not isinstance(value, float):
            raise ValueError("Time must be initialized with a float")
        self.value = value

    def __mul__(self, other: float):
        if not isinstance(other, float):
            raise ValueError("Time can only be multiplied by float")
        return Time(self.value * other)

    def __rmul__(self, other: float):
        return self * other  # multiplication is commutative

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Time({self.value})"

# same for Frequency
```

And then, in your function `f`, you would need to check that the argument is of type `Time`, not just a `float`:

```py
def f(time: Time):
    if not isinstance(time, Time):
        raise ValueError("f requires a Time instance")
    # ...
```

That is not as convenient as what you were hoping for, but it is more in line with how Python's type system is designed to work.
Type hinting in Python is mostly meant as a tool for static analysis and does not affect runtime behavior. Any stricter typing or automatic conversion between types must be implemented in the actual code.

Comment: Thanks! Seems that I've asked a not-even-a-question question. The workaround is nice!